# Excel document missing

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use an excel document every day. I closed it out on Tuesday.
This morning when I turned on my desktop it was gone from my desktop.
I ran Superantivirus and Malwarebytes to check and make sure I wasn't infected.
I have tried everything I know and couldn't find the document.

Comment: Restore from backup. You have backups, right?

Comment: Does it appear in the Recent Documents section of Excel?

Answer (score 2):

If Excel did not create a backup of the file

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/26/recover-unsaved-excel-file/

Recuva has always worked well in the past:

https://www.piriform.com/recuva

Answer (score 0):

First, if you haven't done so already, I'd look in the recycle bin to make sure you didn't inadvertently delete it. To do so, double-click on the recycle bin icon on your desktop. If you did inadvertently delete the file without it going to the recycle bin, like Musselman LLC, I've found Recuva to be helpful in recovering deleted files that aren't in the recycle bin.

I've also encountered cases where someone inadvertently moved a file to another folder unbeknownst to the user. If you have not already searched the entire system, including any externally attached drives, for the file, do so.

If you are using a Microsoft Windows system, you can also check to see if there's a copy of the file saved for you by the Windows [Volume Snapshot Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy), aka Shadow Copy, in a restore point. Using the Windows [File Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer) navigate to the location of your desktop folder. E.g., if your
user name is JDoe, go to `C:\Users\JDoe`. Then right-click on the `Desktop` folder and choose `Properties` then click on the `Previous Versions` tab.